# why the return statement inside main function is terminating unexpectedly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, pytest

I have a requirement wherein I have to perform multiple pyspark transformations and write it to a parquet file. But below are the conditions:

- there are in total 2 files, but at a time either one of them or both could be supplied by the user.
- when x_path file is given then `if i == x_path and x_path != "null"` block should be executed and written to a destination for x_path only.
- when its l_path, then `elif i == l_path and l_path != "null"` block should be executed and written to a destination for l_path only.
- when both the files are passed then `if x_path != "null" and l_path != "null"` block should be executed and written to a destination for both files combined.
- Since I am using pytest for integration testing, writing in the destination shouldn't happen. But the final DF (append_l_x_df) should be returned.

Below is the code snippet. I have tried to make it as close to my actual requirement as possible.

```
def main(x_path, l_path, y_path, test=False):
    for i in [x_path, l_path]:
      if i == x_path and x_path != "null":
        if not test:
          p_df = func.read_parquet_file(x_path)     
        elif test:
            p_df = func.create_spark_dataframe_with_schema(test_p.test_data, test_p.x_schema)
        rename_cols_df = p_df.withColumnRenamed(existingName, newNam)       
        return rename_prem_cols_df
        
        if x_path != "null" and  l_path == "null":
          if not test:
            c_time = func.get_current_timestamp_for_curate_container()
            c_path = <destination_path>
            func.write_df_as_parquet_file(rename_cols_df, c_path, logger)
        
      elif i == l_path and l_path != "null":
        if not test:
          l_df = func.read_parquet_file(l_path)
        elif test:
          l_df = func.create_spark_dataframe_with_schema(test_p.l_test_data, test_p.l_schema)
        split_yr_mnth_qtr_df = func.split_yr_mnth_qtr(rename_ldr_cols_df, "Date", "Year", "Month", "Quarter"
        return split_yr_mnth_qtr_df
        
        if x_path == "null" and  l_path != "null":
          if not test:
            c_time = func.get_current_timestamp_for_curate_container()
            c_path = <destination_path>
            func.write_df_as_parquet_file(split_yr_mnth_qtr_df, c_path, logger)
    
    if test:
      if x_path != "null" and l_path != "null":        
          append_l_x_df = func.union_df([rename_cols_df, split_yr_mnth_qtr_df])
          return append_l_x_df

      elif not test:
        if x_path != "null" and l_path != "null":        
          append_l_x_df = func.union_df([rename_cols_df, split_yr_mnth_qtr_df])
          c_time = func.get_current_timestamp_for_curate_container()
          c_path = <destination_path>

          # Write final data to Curate zone
          func.write_df_as_parquet_file(append_l_x_df, c_path, logger)
          
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(x_path, l_path, y_path, test=False)
```

My problem is when I am executing my test file through pytest, the main python file with above code snippet is executed, but getting terminated at the very first return statement `return rename_prem_cols_df`. Hence my test case(s) are failing. Below are the reason.

- For my test scenario, I have created set of expected schema, which has 26 columns. Those 26 columns are present in the final combined DF, which is `append_l_x_df`.

Since the program is getting terminated at `return rename_prem_cols_df`, so my test is failing, because this DF has different sets of column count.

Note:

- At the time of testing, I am passing 2 files. so, ideally the program should come till the end where we have `append_l_x_df` DF.
- I think that I have not used the return statement at the right places. But not sure if that could be the issue.
- the sample pyspark transformation which I have mentioned in the code snippet is supposed to execute whether or not `test=True`, ie, the transformation should execute even if test mode is False. This part is taken care already as seen in the above snippet.

Comment: Indentation by two spaces hurts my eyes. Inconsistent indention is even worse.

Comment: `return` exits the function. Did you mean to use `continue` or `break`?

Comment: _why the return statement inside main function is terminating unexpectedly_ Because that's what `return` does.  It terminates the function.  If you don't want the function to terminate at that point, don't use `return`.

Comment: `for i in [x_path, l_path]:` is a pointless loop as all you do with `i` is check if it's equal to `x_path` or `l_path` and run different code for each.  You should remove the loop entirely.